# Can't get Reverse Proxy Header / https set up right on Nextcloud through Docker and Nginx Proxy Manager

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, proxy

I thought that I could ignore these warning from Nextcloud:

> Last background job execution ran 22 hours ago. Something seems
> wrong. Check the background job settings ↗.
>
> - The reverse proxy header configuration is  incorrect, or you are accessing Nextcloud from a trusted proxy. If not,  this is a security
>   issue and can allow an attacker to spoof their IP  address as visible
>   to the Nextcloud. Further information can be found in  the
>   documentation ↗.
> - You  are accessing your instance over a secure connection, however your  instance is generating insecure URLs. This most likely means
>   that you  are behind a reverse proxy and the overwrite config
>   variables are not  set correctly. Please read the documentation page
>   about this ↗.

However, my desktop client app won't let me connect when the website works, it says "The polling URL does not start with HTTPS despite the login URL started with HTTPS. Login will not be possible because this might be a security issue. Please contact your administrator". This happens regardless if I put http://cloud.mydomain.com or https://cloud.mydomain.com . I'm using docker, and have Nginx proxy manager and Nextcloud on their own docker containers, but they're on the same nginx2_default network. I have it in the web gui as passing the container name through port 80, as 443 will not work for some reason, but still ends in a SSL connection as long as I tell Nginx Proxy Manager HTTP only, but still pass through a cert.

I've been stuck on this for awhile, and I've made many different posts, but each time it's been a different situation, this is the closest I've gotten, but I still end up with 0 functionality. It's gotta be simple.

I felt it'd be easier to just make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jamess7995/b49aa2083651713c14bd3ffc5fdc73fb) here , that way all docker-compose files are accessible, as well as .htaccess and config files for nextcloud, and I also put docker output there.

I'll paste the most relevant files below though to be easier.
/home/james/newNextcloud/config/config.php

```
  'trusted_domains' =>    array (
    0 => 'cloud.[redacted].com',   ),   array ( 
    'trusted_proxies' => ['172.20.0.12'], 
    'overwritehost' => 'ssl-proxy.tld', 
    'overwriteprotocol' => 'https', 
    'overwritewebroot' => '/cloud.[redacted].com', 
    'overwritecondaddr' => '^172\.20\.0\.12$',    ),   'forwarded_for_headers' =>
    array (
      0 => 'X-Forwarded-For',
      1 => 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',    ),   'datadirectory' => '/var/www/html/data',   'dbtype' => 'mysql',   'version' => '23.0.0.10',   'overwrite.cli.url' => 'https://cloud.[redacted].com',  'dbname' => 'nextcloud',   'dbhost' => 'nextcloud_db',   'dbport' => '',   'dbtableprefix' => 'oc_',   'mysql.utf8mb4' => true,   'dbuser'
=> '[redacted]',   'dbpassword' => '[redacted]',   'installed' => true,   'default_phone_region' => 'US',   'skeletondirectory' => '/var/www/html/fakeskeleton',
```

Docker output:

```
docker ps -a  CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                             COMMAND CREATED       STATUS                 PORTS                             NAMES 7792ac3452db   nextcloud                         "/entrypoint.sh apac…"   2 hours ago   Up 2 hours             0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, :::8080->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->443/tcp, :::8443->443/tcp               nextcloud 8d5a1a2ebc05   nextcloud:fpm-alpine              "/cron.sh"  2 hours ago   Up 2 hours             9000/tcp                          nextcloud2_cron_1 64d024d6ff0c   redis:alpine                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago   Up 2 hours             6379/tcp nextcloud2_redis_1 d1e40d50cd5f   mariadb                           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago   Up 2 hours             3306/tcp nextcloud_db 29fb4aa53f89   plexinc/pms-docker                "/init"  6 hours ago   Up 2 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:3005->3005/tcp, :::3005->3005/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8324->8324/tcp, :::8324->8324/tcp,
0.0.0.0:1900->1900/udp, :::1900->1900/udp, 0.0.0.0:32410->32410/udp, :::32410->32410/udp, 0.0.0.0:32400->32400/tcp, :::32400->32400/tcp,
0.0.0.0:32412-32414->32412-32414/udp, :::32412-32414->32412-32414/udp, 0.0.0.0:32469->32469/tcp, :::32469->32469/tcp   plex 236b0aba1a38   jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest   "/init"                  6 hours ago Up 2 hours             0.0.0.0:80-81->80-81/tcp, :::80-81->80-81/tcp,
0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  npm-ui f81959067233   jc21/mariadb-aria:latest          "/scripts/run.sh"        6 hours ago   Up 2 hours             3306/tcp npm-db


docker container ls CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS                 PORTS    NAMES 7792ac3452db   nextcloud                         "/entrypoint.sh apac…"   2 hours ago   Up 2 hours             0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, :::8080->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->443/tcp, :::8443->443/tcp               nextcloud 8d5a1a2ebc05   nextcloud:fpm-alpine              "/cron.sh"  2 hours ago   Up 2 hours             9000/tcp                          nextcloud2_cron_1 64d024d6ff0c   redis:alpine                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago   Up 2 hours             6379/tcp nextcloud2_redis_1 d1e40d50cd5f   mariadb                           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago   Up 2 hours             3306/tcp nextcloud_db 29fb4aa53f89   plexinc/pms-docker                "/init"  6 hours ago   Up 2 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:3005->3005/tcp, :::3005->3005/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8324->8324/tcp, :::8324->8324/tcp,
0.0.0.0:1900->1900/udp, :::1900->1900/udp, 0.0.0.0:32410->32410/udp, :::32410->32410/udp, 0.0.0.0:32400->32400/tcp, :::32400->32400/tcp,
0.0.0.0:32412-32414->32412-32414/udp, :::32412-32414->32412-32414/udp, 0.0.0.0:32469->32469/tcp, :::32469->32469/tcp   plex 236b0aba1a38   jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest   "/init"                  6 hours ago Up 2 hours             0.0.0.0:80-81->80-81/tcp, :::80-81->80-81/tcp,
0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  npm-ui f81959067233   jc21/mariadb-aria:latest          "/scripts/run.sh"        6 hours ago   Up 2 hours             3306/tcp npm-db


docker volume ls DRIVER    VOLUME NAME local     f6e0828f8a826cf3c8faa9f11b9cda279999f034a8d9e09cfac26bfa0ba9eb16



docker network ls NETWORK ID     NAME                 DRIVER    SCOPE 9cf4b1fc4f1b   bridge               bridge    local 78512dde6d1b   host                 host      local 135921ebe5b5   nextcloud2_default bridge    local 4e52bbf25209   nginx2_default       bridge    local 4de38ef5961d   none                 null      local
```

nextcloud docker compose file

```
version: '2.1'
 
networks:
 nginx2_default:
   external:
     name: nginx2_default
 
services:
  nextcloud:
    image: nextcloud
    container_name: nextcloud
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 8443:443
    networks:
      - nginx2_default
    links:
      - nextcloud_db
    volumes:
      - /home/james/newNextcloud:/var/www/html
      - /newRaid/Nextcloud:/var/www/html/data
    environment:
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=[redacted]
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=[redacted]
      - MYSQL_HOST=nextcloud_db
      - APACHE_DISABLE_REWRITE_IP=1
  nextcloud_db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: nextcloud_db
    restart: always
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW --skip-innodb-read-only-compressed
    networks:
     - nginx2_default
    volumes:
      - /mnt/nextcloud:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=[redacted]
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=[redacted]
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=[redacted]
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    restart: always  
  cron:
    image: nextcloud:fpm-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /home/james/newNextcloud:/var/www/html
    entrypoint: /cron.sh
    depends_on:
      - nextcloud_db
      - redis
```

Nginx Proxy Manager docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    container_name: npm-ui
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      # These ports are in format <host-port>:<container-port>
      - '80:80' # Public HTTP Port
      - '443:443' # Public HTTPS Port
      - '81:81' # Admin Web Port
        # - '32400:32400'  For Plex
      # Add any other Stream port you want to expose
      # - '21:21' # FTP
    environment:
      DB_MYSQL_HOST: "db"
      DB_MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      DB_MYSQL_USER: "[redacted]"
      DB_MYSQL_PASSWORD: "[redacted]"
      DB_MYSQL_NAME: "npm"
      # Uncomment this if IPv6 is not enabled on your host
      # DISABLE_IPV6: 'true'
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.12
    depends_on:
      - db
 
  db:
    image: 'jc21/mariadb-aria:latest'
    container_name: npm-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '[redacted]'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'npm'
      MYSQL_USER: '[redacted]'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '[redacted]'
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.22

networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
```

Answer (score 0):

So your files helped me solve this problem for me so I will share my config file back to you.

```
root@linux:/apps/nextcloud/app/config# vim config.php
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'htaccess.RewriteBase' => '/',
  'memcache.local'`` => '\\OC\\Memcache\\APCu',
  'apps_paths' =>
  array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'path' => '/var/www/html/apps',
      'url' => '/apps',
      'writable' => false,
    ),
    1 =>
    array (
      'path' => '/var/www/html/custom_apps',
      'url' => '/custom_apps',
      'writable' => true,
    ),
  ),
  'instanceid' => 'ocsdfgfsdg5',
  'passwordsalt' => 'Wsdgsdfgsdfgsd2IO/nY',
  'secret' => 'Asdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg',
  'trusted_domains' =>
  array (
    0 => 'cloud.sdfgfdsgsfd.org',
   ),
  'trusted_proxies' =>
  array (
    0 => '10.1.5.124',
  ),
  'overwriteprotocol' => 'https',
  'datadirectory' => '/var/www/html/data',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'version' => '23.0.2.1',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'http://cloud.fsdghfgsdh.org',
  'dbname' => 'fghfdgsh',
  'dbhost' => 'fghjdfdg',
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbtableprefix' => 'oc_',
  'mysql.utf8mb4' => true,
  'dbuser' => 'dfhgfghdh',
  'dbpassword' => 'dfghfdgh',
  'installed' => true,
);
```